# PHP data collection - use class construct to replace numerical key with string ident

Tags: php, arrays, class, object, key-value

I am experimenting with data collection objects and want to use the class construct to make changes to the array keys of arrays passed to a newly instantiated object.

The main idea is that arrays can be passed with numerical keys and each numerical key will then be replaced with a string value. The system is predicated on the fact that arrays will only a single array of array each containing three key/value pairs. (see data example). I know this is very fragile and i intend to address this issue next.

**Class:**

```
class newsCollection {

    private $collection;

    public function __construct($data)
    {
        foreach ($data[0] as $key => $value) {

            switch ($key) {
                case 0:
                    // Replace key ID with a string ie. 0 with "headline"
                    break;
                case 1:
                    // Replace key ID with a string ie. 1 with "date"
                    break;
                case 2:
                    // Replace key ID with a string ie. 2 with "author"
                    break;
            }
        }

        $this->collection = $data;
    }

    public function getNewsCollection()
    {
        return $this->collection;
    }
}
```

**Data (array):**

```
$sports = [
    [
        "Boston Red Sox vs New York Yankees - 9-3",
        "19.06.2017",
        "ESPN"
    ],
    [
       "Boston Patriot QB breaks new record!",
       "16.07.2017",
       "NESN"
    ],
    [
        "Celtics coach John Doe inducted into hall of fame",
        "25.07.2017",
        "Fox Sports"
    ],
    [
        "Boston Brewins win 16-5 against New York's Rangers",
        "21.08.2017",
        "NESN"
    ]
];
```

**Example of desire result:**

```
$sports = [
    [
        "headline" => Boston Red Sox vs New York Yankees - 9-3",
        "date => "19.06.2017",
        "author" => "ESPN"
    ],
    ect..
];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make an `array` with your desired keys, and then use `array_combine()` to set them as keys of your input `array`. Something like this:

```
private $keys = [
    "headline",
    "date",
    "author",
];

// ...

public function __construct($data)
{
    foreach ($data as &$el) {
        $el = array_combine($this->keys, $el);
    }

    $this->collection = $data;
}
```

Notice it's done by reference, so we're modifying the actual element inside the `foreach` loop. You should also do some verification according to your needs.

As a side note, you should [not do any work in the constructor](http://misko.hevery.com/code-reviewers-guide/flaw-constructor-does-real-work/). It'll bring you problems down the road. It's better to have another function do the initial work with your input values:

```
<?php
class newsCollection {

    private $collection;
    private $keys = [
        "headline",
        "date",
        "author",
    ];

    public function __construct($data)
    {
        $this->collection = $data;
    }

    public function assingKeys() {
        foreach ($this->collection as &$el) {
            $el = array_combine($this->keys, $el);
        }
    }

    public function getNewsCollection()
    {
        return $this->collection;
    }
}

$c = new newsCollection($sports);
$c->assignKeys();
$collection = $c->getNewsCollection();
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/AIeUq)

Comment: Thank, this worked a charm, but there are some elements i am a bit unsure about. 1. What is the "`&`" in "`&el`" in reference to ? originally i thought i was a type but it became clear it had a purpose. 2. To reduce the number og methods called could i run the "`assignKeys()`" method in the constructor?

Comment: 1. It’s called [passing by reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php). It’s so you modify each element directly. Otherwise you’d have to modify the element and create a new array with each element. 2. No, don’t do any work in the constructor if at all possible. It’s better to only fully form your object in it. Any other work should be done in it’s own method. It’s clearer, much easier to test, etc. Try reading the article I included, it’s awesome!

Comment: Thank you for the clarification and the links!

Answer (score 1):

Simply create temporary array and assign it to collection. change your `constructor` as :

```
public function __construct($data)
    {
      $new_data = array();
        foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
           if(is_array($value))
           {
              $new_data_tmp["headline"] = isset($value[0])?$value[0]:"";
              $new_data_tmp["date"] = isset($value[1])?$value[1]:"";
              $new_data_tmp["author"] = isset($value[2])?$value[2]:"";
              $new_data[] = $new_data_tmp;
           }
        }

        $this->collection = $new_data;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks you for your response but the answer from @ishegg was much closer to the solution i wanted.